# Как достать объекты из json

Tags: java, json, парсер

Есть такой json файл, нужно получить из него массив объектов

```
{"user": {
    "data": "some data",
    "num": 10,
    "name": "Name",
    "id": 14
}}
{"user": {
    "data": "another some data",
    "num": 11,
    "name": "Name1",
    "id": 15
}}
{"user": {
    "data": "another new some data",
    "num": 12,
    "name": "Name2",
    "id": 16
}}
```

Comment: Это не JSON. *(3 символа нужно...)*

Comment: это не JSON, но если эта информация статическая , то по сути можно распарсить руками, это несложно. привести все к массиву вида {
    "data": "another new some data",
    "num": 12,
    "name": "Name2",
    "id": 16
}, а это уже JSON))

Answer (score 0):

Например так :

использую гугловую библиотеку для JSON

compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'

```
public List<User> parse (final String data) {        
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    int start=-1;
    final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i)=='{') start=i;
        if (data.charAt(i)=='}'&&start!=-1) {
            users.add(gson.fromJson(data.substring(start, i+1), User.class));
            start=-1;
        }
    }        
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если этот формат строгий, то дополните его до Json Array путем добавления [ в начало, ] в конец и заменой }{ на },{. затем дело техники используйте Gson от Google gson.fromJson(String jsonarray, typeOfT)